# Unable to play midi file using vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beD7o.png)I'm trying to Play a midi file Using VBA editor. But After Assigning the Macro..
Its is Showing "Click OK when the MIDI file starts playing..."..But the song is not playing. Both the song and excel are in same folder.
So, Can anyone please tell where the mistake is? What went Wrong?

```
Private Declare Function mciExecute Lib "winmm.dll" _
                         (ByVal lpstrCommand As String) As Long

Sub PlayMidiFile(Indiana_Jones_And_The_Last_Crusade__Main_Theme As String, Play As Boolean)
    If Dir(Indiana_Jones_And_The_Last_Crusade__Main_Theme) = "" Then Exit Sub ' no file to play
    If Play Then
        mciExecute "play " & Indiana_Jones_And_The_Last_Crusade__Main_Theme ' start playing
    Else
        mciExecute "stop " & Indiana_Jones_And_The_Last_Crusade__Main_Theme ' stop playing
    End If
End Sub

Sub TestPlayMidiFile()
    PlayMidiFile "C:\Users\nulik\Desktop\music sairam", True
    MsgBox "Click OK when the MIDI file starts playing..."
    MsgBox "Click OK to stop playing the MIDI file..."
    PlayMidiFile "C:\Users\nulik\Desktop\music sairam", False
End Sub
```

Comment: When I run it..It is just Showing that "Click ok when music starts Playing and Click ik when music stops Playing".But It is not actually Playing the Song.I could not find any errors too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the complete path for the midifile with the midifile name and file extenstion (".mid" or ".midi"):

```
PlayMidiFile "C:\Users\nulik\Desktop\music sairam\Indiana_Jones_And_The_Last_Crusade__Main_Theme.mid", True 

PlayMidiFile "C:\Users\nulik\Desktop\music sairam\Indiana_Jones_And_The_Last_Crusade__Main_Theme.mid", False
```

---

EDIT: I got it to work, both on Excel 2010-32 bit and 2016-64bit:

Add `PtrSafe` in the "Private Declare Function" if you have 64-bit system. 32-bit system could have `PtrSafe`. Execute "`Sub TestPlayMidiFile`" to play midi file.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function mciExecute Lib "winmm.dll" _
(ByVal lpstrCommand As String) As Long

Sub PlayMidiFile(MidiFileName As String, Play As Boolean)
    If Dir(MidiFileName) = "" Then Exit Sub ' no file to play
    If Play Then
        mciExecute "play " & MidiFileName ' start playing
    Else
        mciExecute "stop " & MidiFileName ' stop playing
    End If
End Sub

Sub TestPlayMidiFile()
    PlayMidiFile "G:\Till\robert_miles__fable__dream_remix__unknown.mid", True
    MsgBox "Click OK when the MIDI file starts playing..."
    MsgBox "Click OK to stop playing the MIDI file..."
    PlayMidiFile "G:\Till\robert_miles__fable__dream_remix__unknown.mid", False
End Sub
```

Comment: I Have a Doubt..In the Place of MdiFileName,Should I place my music file name or should I leave it the same?And Also..When I run The Modue..It is Showing that "specified Device is not open or not found by MCI" ..Please Help.@Wizhi

Comment: MdiFileName was the original name for the variable, that doesn't matter as long it's same everywhere.

Comment: When I run The Modue..It is Showing that "specified Device is not open or not found by MCI" ..Please Help.@Wizhi

Comment: AFAIK the `PtrSafe` keyword is *available* in 32-bit VBA as well if you use versions **>= Office 2010** (conditional compiler constant `VBA7`); in actually installed 64bit Versions you have to use it. BTW the LongPtr data type, too. So, you can and should write API code that runs in both environments. There are only a few examples where you have to distinguish between `Win64` and `Win32` installations.

Comment: I'm not sure about that statement issue. For me it worked after I changed the fileextenstions. Maybe either of this two links could help you: [Specified device not open or not recognized by MCI?](https://www.itprotoday.com/compute-engines/jsi-tip-10090-specified-device-not-open-or-not-recognized-mci) or [Specified device not open or not recognized by MCI](https://forums.spybot.info/showthread.php?9281-Specified-device-not-open-or-not-recognized-by-MCI)

Comment: I saw your image and noticed, what happens if you move the file and change it an easier location such as directly under the file directory of "C:\Indiana_Jones_And_The_Last_Crusade__Main_Theme.mid"...